# Ubuntu Google chrome, Source tab not working

Tags: google-chrome

I have Ubuntu version 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) . I removed the old packages

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I updated Ubuntu with the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then installed docker

```
docker compose version
sudo apt remove docker-desktop
rm -r $HOME/.docker/desktop
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli
sudo apt purge docker-desktop
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
echo   "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

And in my working directory I changed all the pros to the pros of my user with the command

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u -n):$(uid -u -n) /home/$(id -u -n)
```

then removed the package

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and installed the library
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
Now my chrome tab "Source" is not working

[image]

Comment: I haven't done all that, my chrome source tab isn't working after the latest Ubuntu update.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.